# Limiting Web Apps To Certain Devices Or locations

Tags: c#, security, web-applications

If I was developing a Web App for (n) amount of business(users) and I wanted the users to be able to limit where the app could be used (in their premises or other speciifc locations) would this be possible?

As an example: A IT manager could limit the app usage to the machines in the office and also other designated offices but no where else.

Is it a good idea to limit the app to certain IP address's.

Comment: You can set your application only work in specific domain name(s).

Comment: Would that Active Domain?

Comment: I don't understand you. Please Explain more.

Comment: i'm sorry is that Active Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i did not understand what you exactly want so i write my answer hope to help you:
Create a list for your domain names and check if current domain name is one of them or not.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> Domains = new List<string> { "www.domain1.com", "www.domain2.com", "www.domain3.com" };
        string currentDomain = Request.Url.Host;
        //string currentDomain = Request.Url.Authority; //Returns localhost:1234 if you want to test in localhost
        if (!Domains.Contains(currentDomain.ToLower()))
            throw new Exception("Domain name is not considered");
    }
```

Application_BeginRequest is a part of your Global.cs file of your application
therefore if your app has not global file add this.

Comment: Thank you - Is it possible for a hacker to spoof their IP address so it appears to be from a trusted address?

Comment: You welcome - No one can change address list but you, because they are in codes compiled in your-app.dll file.